# Exporting a JAR file in eclipse, seems fine but one of my classes does not work

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm trying to export a project of mine containing four classes to a jar file (not executable) using the eclipse export method. everything seems to go fine, all four classes show up in the referenced libraries once I have added them to another program.

However, when importing the classes back into a program, I can only see three of them. One of them (the same one each time) does not show up to be imported. Any suggestions as to what might be causing this or how to fix it?

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project before I export it, but this doesn't help.

Thanks!

EDIT: Solution has been added to answers, apologies but I discovered the issue.

Comment: How are you importing the classes back in the program? Do you mean you exported the classes along with source as a JAR file and now you are trying to import the jar as a project in eclipse??

Comment: Hi there. I had the JAR file fully formed and it was already added to the librarys list. I was using the import statement and one of the classes wasnt appearing there. However, I discovered the problem. It seems at some point, the class that was giving me problems had lost its "public" modifier. Adding this back in corrected my issue. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

I apologise everybody but i discovered the solution. The class that was giving me issues had lost it's public modifier at somepoint, probably during refactoring. Once i'd added it back, the jar file behaved properly. Sorry about that.